# iOS monospaced hexadecimal values

Tags: ios, ios11, monospace

I love the San Francisco font. And would like to use it if possible. I have a table view that shows a series of labels where each label is 6 hexadecimal digits, e.g.

```
F0:1A:2B
12:CE:88
```

The problem is that they don't line up nicely. I can enable the monospaced digits attribute for the font, but that doesn't account for the characters ABCDEF. I've tried the single monospace font (Menlo) and it looks terrible and out of place.

I'm toying with making 8 little labels one for each character (6 hex digits plus the two : separators), which seems like a huge kludge. Is there no other way. I wondered if there was a way to do something with `AttributedString` to get the hex digits to be same width?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38560422/how-to-make-characters-equal-width-in-uilabel

Comment: @GuyKogus are you referring to the Kerning solution there? It's not clear how you apply the kerning? Do I need to figure out a unique value for each of ABCDEF? (and let the monospace digits take care of the others?)

Comment: Sorry no, I meant the answer from @Warpling, which shows how to force a font to function as monospaced.

Comment: Yeah, that only does the digits, not the A-F letter, unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, then @aaron-bratcher's got the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a proportionally spaced font, you'll have to draw the characters at the appropriate places. Otherwise, find a monospaced font you like.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake, I should post what I ended up doing after accepting what @AaronBratcher confirmed.

First I created 5 separate UILabels for the following elements:

```
leftTwoDigits-leftSeparator-centerTwoDigits-rightSeparator-rightTwoDigits
```

I used constrains to constrain all of their baselines, and have 0 horizontal spacing betwixt each. The separator labels were set simply to `:` and normal color. The xxxTwoDigits labels were given the string `AA`. `A` is NOT the widest character, `C is`. But `A` is near it. `C` is too wide, and `A` is wide enough. The color of these labels was set to `clear` so it doesn't actually show up.

Then 6 more UILabels are added. Again the the same baselines. The first two are constrained to the leading and trailing sides of leftTwoDigits and constrained to match in width. Repeat for the other 4 cells. Make all centered. And populate them individually with the individual digits.